# Вызвать из html метод в js

Tags: html, javascript

Возможно ли из блока div, в момент его создания, вызвать определенный метод в js?

Comment: Возможно, вам нужен https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @RubaXa: Спасибо! Почитал про него и не могу определится, как к нему относится.
Кто говорит, что это - хорошо, кто - плохо. Вы его пробовали? Какие у Вас о нем мысли, как у опытного программиста?

Comment: Хорошая штука, но я работаю со старыми браузерами, так что не для меня. Помимо этого, архитектура приложения написана так, что это просто не требуется. MutationObserver низкоуровневый компонент, очень.

Comment: Спасибо.      .